# Automatically Login Gmail Account

Tags: php, authentication, gmail, google-oauth

I want to automatically authenticate and login into a Gmail Account via a php script.

Since it wont be possible to authenticate via App using username + password from 2024 on, i am looking for a new way to do that.

I read about authenticating via OAuth but that requires the User Consent and i am not sure if that means, i can not login via script automatically. I should get an Access Token with that method but i dont see any in the user credentials i obtained, so i am confused if its possible with OAuth.

So basically i am asking, if its possible to authenticate and login a Gmail User automatically via script and what i would need for that.

Comment: The user has to give your app consent only once. You will then be able to make API requests in their name, for as long as the token is valid.

Comment: try this approach, let me know if it works? https://www.codexworld.com/login-with-google-api-using-php/

Comment: If you just want to log into the same fixed account every time you may be able to use a Service Account. Check the Google API authentication docs for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to automatically authenticate and login into a Gmail Account via a php script.

You have a few options.

1. SMTP  (XOAuth, or apps password)
2. Gmail API (Oauth2 or Service account)

Authorization methods

1. Service accounts (only works with google workspace)
2. Oauth2 and store the refresh token.
3. Apps password.

> Since it wont be possible to authenticate via App using username + password from 2024 on, i am looking for a new way to do that.

This is in correct in 2015 google removed client login an option for its APIs.  Im not sure where you got 2024 from.

> I read about authenticating via OAuth but that requires the User Consent and i am not sure if that means, i can not login via script automatically. I should get an Access Token with that method but i dont see any in the user credentials i obtained, so i am confused if its possible with OAuth.

Access private user data will always require consent of the user to get access. Oauth2 is a way of requesting access from a user to access their data.  Depending upon the language you are using you get an access token returned which is valid for one hour and a refresh token which is long lived and can be used to request a new access token as you need.

You can also use service accounts, service accounts are preauthorized so do not require a user consent.

> So basically i am asking, if its possible to authenticate and login a Gmail User automatically via script and what i would need for that.

Depends largely on if this is a google workspace account. If it is create a service account and configure domain wide delegation.

If its not authorize the application once store the refresh token and have your code use that refresh token when ever it needs to run the code.